# Accessing a global vector component using a logical condition inside a function

Tags: r, vector

This function returns people's BMIs. The function the returns the BMIs does what I want but I cannot figure out how to print the **WEIGHTS** of those people that have a BMI over 25.  I feel like I should be subscripting but how do I get that association? Thanks in advance.

```
heights_in_cms <- c(180, 165, 160, 193)
weights_in_kg  <- c(87, 58, 65, 100)

bmi_calc <- function(h, w) {
  bmi = w / (h / 100)^2
  cat("BMIs are:", bmi, "\n")

  for (b in bmi) {
    if (b > 25) {
      print(b)
    }
  }
}
bmi_seq <- bmi_calc(heights_in_cms, weights_in_kg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
bmi_calc <- function(h, w) {
 bmi = w/(h/100)^2
 print(list(`BMIs are:` = bmi[bmi > 25], 
            `Weights are:` = w[bmi > 25]))
}

bmi_calc(heights_in_cms, weights_in_kg)

$`BMIs are:`
[1] 26.85185 25.39062 26.84636

$`Weights are:`
[1]  87  65 100
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to R. Would this be considered the "R way" of doing this or just your basic logic for any language?

Comment: Subsetting using `x[y]` could be considered the "R way". But I'm sure other languages are using the same logic.

Comment: The function should return `bmi` and `w` invisibly (in a list). `print` should be used instead of `cat`.

Comment: I use subscripting often to access specific elements obviously, but have never used it with logical operators as the subscript in R. I think it looks confusing to me simply because the names of the declared variables are the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

using the same method as [tmfmnk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62281814/10442423) you can get make the output of the function a dataframe if you prefer.

```
bmi_calc <- function(h, w) {
    bmi <- w/(h/100)^2
    return(data.frame(BMI=bmi[bmi > 25], Weight = w[bmi > 25]))
}

> bmi_calc(heights_in_cms, weights_in_kg)

       BMI Weight
1 26.85185     87
2 25.39062     65
3 26.84636    100
```

Edit: from the discussion in the comments

```
data.frame(Height.cm=heights_in_cms, Weight.kg=weights_in_kg, BMI=weights_in_kg*(heights_in_cms/100)^2)

  Height.cm Weight.kg     BMI
1       180        87 281.880
2       165        58 157.905
3       160        65 166.400
4       193       100 372.490
```

Comment: Damn, that looks nice. I'm assuming that's the more expected route for analytics which is what I'm studying now with R and Python.

Comment: The advantage is the object is re-usable, sub-settable, etc. The `cat` output is essentially a string that's only use is to be printed.

Comment: Yeah, looks the same minus the df. I guess I should always try to use this syntax instead since I'll always be dealing with dataframes. So using the dataframe syntax just puts it in a table format instead then. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, but then again, it is not printing ALL of the BMIs.

Comment: Thast because of the logical `bmi >25` it can easily be removed if you wish.

Comment: without any function at all, you could simply write `data.frame(Height.cm=heights_in_cms, Weight.kg=weights_in_kg, BMI=weights_in_kg*(heights_in_cms/100)^2)` I've edited this into the answer so you can see.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the extra info.